# What does "worth climb into" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "worth climb into" mean in:

> it (a place in Brooklyn) was a very good street, but not really worth a climb into Queens.

Thanks.

Comment: It's "worth **a** climb into" - the article can't be omitted here.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for sure without seeing more context, but I think it is referring to the fact that Queens (NY) is not a very easy area to get through, especially by car. In other words, it's saying something along the lines of:

> *This place is Brooklyn is a nice place to visit. I'd go there more often if I didn't have to go through Queens to get there*.

Because Brooklyn is west of Queens, I'm assuming the author resides (or perhaps works) east of Queens.

[image]

This usage of *a climb into* appears to be slang. It's roughly equivalent to:

> it was a very good street, but not really worth **the trouble of getting through** Queens.

---

**EDIT**: I did a Google search, and found your quote on [this page](http://www.streetadvisor.com/234th-st-laurelton-queens-new-york-city-new-york). According to that page, the place in question is not in Brooklyn, but in Queens.

Since that website is devoted to giving reviews about residential places to live, and it's talking about a street in Queens, I'm going to give a new paraphrase:

> This is a very good street to live on, but not really worth **the hassle of relocating** to Queens.

In other words: "I'd love to live on this street, if it was located someplace else."

This usage of "climb into" would be similar to when we say "climb into bed." It means you're moving somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. The same reviewer used the same sentence in a comment on a place in Brooklyn.

Comment: @Tim - Interesting. Perhaps both meanings apply then. That reviewer seems to like that word :-)